# Disable and re-enable image tracking ARKit

Tags: unity, c#, augmented-reality

Is there a way to disable and re-enable tracking for images in ARKit? From the older versions, this was the solution. But the newer versions have removed the `UnityARSessionNativeInterface` script.

```
void Start ()
{
    m_session = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface();
}

void AddImageAnchor(ARImageAnchor arImageAnchor)
{
    //at the bottom of this function
    StartCoroutine(RemoveAnchorCoroutine(arImageAnchor));
}

IEnumerator RemoveAnchorCoroutine(ARImageAnchor anchor)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
    //doesn't have to be in a coroutine, but for my uses it is
    m_session.RemoveUserAnchor(anchor.identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497462); I'm copying it here in case it gets removed from SO.

---

The current ARKit API doesn't have a method to disable or enable it in Unity, during run-time at this point.

With than being said, Unity has its own function to enable and disable VR, AR or XR plugins. If ARKit is built correctly, this method should work. So, you might be able to disable/enable ARKit by setting `XRSettings.enabled` to `false` and enable it by setting it to `true`.

It's also a good idea to call `XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName` with an empty string, wait for frame, before setting `XRSettings.enabled` to `false` to disable it:

```
IEnumerator DisableAR()
{
    XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName("");
    yield return null;
    XRSettings.enabled = false;
}
```

then call to disable:

```
StartCoroutine(DisableAR());
```